# Keycloak backup operation

Tags: backup, keycloak

I'm reading the documentation from Keycloak for the [export operation](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-adminstration-guide/content/topics/export-import.html#) in order to setup a backup operation (e.g. via a cron job) and what it says is that export is happending during server startup:

> Export and import is triggered at server boot time and its parameters
>   are passed in via Java system properties. It is important to note that
>   because import and export happens at server startup, no other actions
>   should be taken on the server or the database while this happens.

While it has a point, that no other operation is happening during the export operation I was wondering what is the *best practice* to keep backups of your existing keycloak data? Should the cron job for instance reboot the keycloak server every one per Week to keep the backup, or should I consider a backup operation on the database side (RDBMS)?

Answer (score 6):

Go inside "Keycloak/bin/" folder and run below command to export all realms data.

> sh standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export
>   -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile -Dkeycloak.migration.file=keycloak-export.json -Djboss.http.port=8888 -Djboss.https.port=9999 -Djboss.management.http.port=7777

This will export everything but change ports which your using in "Standard.xml" file.
Also, if you want to backup users as well, you can look into  this guide:

https://github.com/slim-hmidi/keycloak-export-realm

Export your realm data and you can always take your postgres database backup or you can run cron job to take backup.

> 0 * * * 0 pg_dump -U postgres dbname > ~/postgres/backups/dbname.bak

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this *isn't* best practice, but if you're using the default H2 database that you get with `standalone.(bat|sh)`:

```
peter@machine:~/keycloak-10.0.2$ cat /tmp/query.sql
SCRIPT TO '/tmp/db-dump.sql'

peter@machine:~/keycloak-10.0.2$ java -cp \
    ./modules/system/layers/base/com/h2database/h2/main/h2-1.4.197.jar \
     org.h2.tools.RunScript \
     -url "jdbc:h2:file:./standalone/data/keycloak" \
     -user sa -password sa -script /tmp/query.sql -showResults

peter@machine:~/keycloak-10.0.2$ less /tmp/db-dump.sql
```

Got the inspiration from [this post](https://jonas.verhoelen.de/databases/dump-sql-h2-database-file/).